# Application crashes when saving in CoreData concurrently in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Application crashes when saving in Core data

```
do {
   try context.save()  <-----------  CRASH ---------
} catch {
   print("Failed saving")
}
```

I save data in Core data in background using this code

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // Fetches from database                
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             if fetchedActivitiesFromDB {
                 // Updates the view
             } else {
                 // gets from the server
                 // Save the result in Core Data <------------
                 let coreData = CoreDataHelper()
                 coreData.saveInDB(fetchedItemsFromServer)
             }
        }                 
}
```

According to above code this is possible to save in CoreData concurrently.
I did some tasks to resolve the problem but they didn't work.

**First:** I wanted to create a queue in order to handle concurrent save

```
let saveQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "start save in CoreData");
saveQueue.async {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
           do {
              try context.save()
           } catch {
              print("Failed saving")
           }
        }
 }
```

The above code didn't solve the problem.

**Second**: The CoreDataManager was not singleton. I thought that this was the problem, so I changed it to:

```
class CoreDataHelper {

    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataHelper()

    private init() {}

    static func getInstance() ->  CoreDataHelper {
        return sharedInstance
    }
    //...
}
```

**Third**: I changed the CoreData Stack setting

```
static var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

        return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

ConcurrencyType used to be **mainQueueConcurrencyType**

None of these changes resolved the problem

***Crash detail:***

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000014153'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18485cf48 0x19940ff80 0x184863c5c 0x184860c00 0x184764cac 0x18482c978 0x18476de38 0x18460f134 0x1845ebda0 0x1845ed47c 0x18453f2fc 0x184509f04 0x1845d0fdc 0x1845d8fd8 0x1025b5c68 0x1025c181c 0x1845cb830 0x184509ab0 0x18452e1d8 0x1005bce00 0x10029e498 0x100484a08 0x1003c097c 0x1003ca13c 0x1001296e8 0x1025b5ca8 0x1025b5c68 0x1025bb710 0x1848141f8 0x184812060 0x184740ca0 0x18f97c088 0x189e58ffc 0x10011c8e0 0x199c5e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: could you provide more information about the crash? What is the Exception that CoreData is printing you in the console?

Comment: @MarcelT Thanks, I added details of crash to the answer.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi I'm also experiencing some rare crashes when saving from background. Did you ever solve this? I now tried to wrap the `do { try context.save() } catch { ... }` in a `context.performAndWait`, but I'm not sure yet if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {


    func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{

        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        return appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    }

    func saveDataToCoreData(username:String,password:String) -> Bool{

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Entity", in: getContext())
        let manageObect = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: getContext())

        manageObect.setValue(username,forKey:password)
        do{
         try getContext().save()

         return true
        }
        catch{
            return false
        }
    }

    func fetchAllData() -> [Entity]?{

        do{
            let result:[Entity]? = try getContext().fetch(Entity.fetchRequest())
            return result
        }
        catch{

           return nil
        }
    }

    func delete(ManagedObj:Entity) -> Bool{

        getContext().delete(ManagedObj)

        do{
            try getContext().save()

            return true
        }
        catch{
            return false
        }


    }

    func cleanMyCoreData() -> Bool{

        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest:Entity.fetchRequest())
        do{
            try getContext().execute(delete)

            return true
        }
        catch{
            return false
        }

    }

    func filterByPredicate(pred:NSPredicate) -> [Entity]?{

        let fetchReq:NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()

        fetchReq.predicate = pred

        do{

            let entity =   try getContext().fetch(fetchReq)

            return entity

        }
        catch{
            return nil
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: I think you need to explain your answer a little more.

Comment: Could you explain please